# Google Play Beta Version Error

Tags: android, google-play

Currently we are using Google Alpha and Beta to house a staging and production version of our APK. Staging is placed in Alpha and has the version number range of 4.X.X. Production is placed in Google Beta and has the version number range 1.X.X. We are doing this before we launch our product to the mass public later this year and when we do so, we will be using Google Play Beta and Production - with our staging APK going to Beta and Production APK going to Production.

We have been through three releases so far:

4.6.4 Staging / 1.0.1 Production - October 2014

4.7.2 Staging / 1.1.0 Production - December 2014

4.8.2 Staging / 1.2.0 Production - January 2015

Just to note we are not actually the ones publishing in Google Play - we have three companies that use this product for their customers and each has their own Google Play account and publishes their own app (though all three are the same).

One of our companies looks to have published a staging version of the APK into Google Beta at some point by mistake. Due to our staging APK having a high version number than our production APK, Google Play is not allowing the production APK to be uploaded for the January release. What doesn't make any sense is that Google Play is throwing the error from version 4.6.2 which was released in October 2014. The same company was able to successfully upload 1.1.0 into Google Play Beta in December without an issue.

Is there a way to get Google Play to forget about this version 4.6.2 that seems to keep throwing it up? We have no idea how this has happened or the correct way to allow the lower version number of the APK into Google Play Beta.

Screenshots from the companies Google Play account can be found here:

http://tinypic.com/r/wgzxc1/8
http://tinypic.com/r/20gl40j/8

Answer (score 0):

In the top-right of the Google Play developer console's APK tab, there's a *Switch to advanced mode* button. Enable that, and then you get a drop-down containing several options for the current APK, one of which is *Deactivate*.

[image]

If you deactivate the erroneously-uploaded APK, I think that will allow you to upload the correct version.

Comment: The 40602000 version is not currently active and is showing as unpublished in Google Beta, so I think what you have suggested has already been done.